# Invalid Pattern name; Oracle Stored Procedure Input Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I have a JDBC program to which uses a `CallabaleStatement` object to set and register IN/OUT parameters for the stored procedure.

I have used `ArrayDescriptor`s and `oracle.sql.ARRAY` object and set it as an input parameter with the user-defined datatype.

The User defined datatype is `TYPE CharArray1 IS TABLE OF CHAR(7)`. During the executing the error, I receive is "invalid pattern name my-object".

I set the input in the following way:

```
ArrayDescriptor ad = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("<package-name>.CharArray1", conn);
ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(ad, conn, new String[]{"1"});
callableStatement.setArray(3, arr );
```

where `conn` is my `Connection` Object. I have checked the Execute permission for the `package-name` for the Datatype `CharArray1`. I have removed the package-name and checked, the error remain the same.

Thanks in advance. Please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch `CHAR` to VARCHAR2(7 char)

Comment: My functionality needs it to be a `table of char(7)`. I can not make database changes. I need to make the Java code to keep up.

Comment: But you send only 1 byte, try to add 6 white spaces. When you finish the project read some Thomas Kyte books, he wants us **NOT TO USE** the `CHAR` type over the `VARCHAR2` type. There is no advantages.

Comment: It is not necessarily that I will be adding 1 everytime. The number of character can be "12345", for example.

Comment: Anyway you have to watch that you pass 7 byte(not characters, one character can take several bytes) and add white spaces if necessary.

Comment: Agreed which I will take care. The values that come to this will definitely not be more than 7 byte. But, I feel that is not the concern here. I would like to know, if there are any changes to the way I'm passing the parameter to the CallableStatement.

Comment: The point is you can't use strings with dynamic length. If you work with `CHAR` you have to pass strings with exact length, for you the length is 7 byte. As a solution you can add a wrapper around the function you are trying to call and pass there a `VARCHAR` collection. From this function (wrapper) you will call the function you want to reach. I guess it is the best solution for you.

Comment: I could try this. But are you certain that the reason error occurs is  because I am passing 1 byte instead of 7 ?

Comment: At least you can try, when you work in PL/SQL with the `CHAR` type Oracle adds white spaces automatically if it is necessary, but you work through `jdbc` there might be some limits.

Comment: Alright. I will try both the ways. Adding white spaces and changing to `VARCHAR`

Thank you so much for your support. I will reply back to the thread in case this fails. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I couldn't try the VARCHAR change. But I have tried the other changes. Like providing the name in Upper Caps and mentioning the package name. The error is same. Could you please suggest another approach to eliminate this error?